# Excel email macro seems to be triggered whenever a cell is populated

Tags: vba, email, excel

I have a excel spreadsheet which tracks important dates, if you have missed an invoice for that date it will automatically send out an email to the relevant person reminding them to do so. The macro functions well and works off a trigger

`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
lr = Sheets("2015").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For r = lr To 2 Step -1

If Range("Q" & r).Value = "Received" Then
        Call Macro1
    End If

If Range("K" & r).Value = "Overdue" Then
        Call email
    End If


Next r
End Sub
```

`

```
Sub email()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim FName As String


Sheets("2015").Activate

For i = 1 To 100
If Sheets("2015").Range("K" & i).Value = "Overdue" Then


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
FName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
With OutMail
.To = Sheets("2015").Range("S" & i).Value
.CC = ""
.Subject = Sheets("2015").Range("B" & i).Value
.Body = "You have missed a valuation date for this project!"

.Send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing


End If
Next i

End Sub

'
```

As you can see I am new to this so most of my code is from different examples on the internet. The problem I have is that when a cell in column K meets the requirements "Overdue" the macro will repeatedly email the user when a change in any other cell occurs. That is if K5 = "Overdue" and I go to A6 to enter a new user, the user in A5 will be emailed again. This happens for all cells until I change cell k5 to "sent".

I suspect part of the problem may also be in my e-mail macro...

I give up XD

Comment: add another column `Status` which has a string saying `sent/not sent` and only email when it's not send yet,

Comment: You could add another status - "Overdue - Mail sent" and have the status flipped whenever an email is sent

Answer (score 0):

Your macro's are working fine, I mean at least as you code them. You need to remove your macro's form `FOR` loops. What you can do is just getting the address of the changed cell and use it to define the mail address and subject. Something like below

** Worksheet macros**

```
Public mailAddress As String
Public TargetRow As Long
Public mailSubject

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Value = "Overdue" Then
    mailAddress = Sheets("2015").Range("S" & Target.Row)
    mailSubject = Sheets("2015").Range("B" & Target.Row)
    TargetRow = Target.Row
    Call email
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Received" Then
        Call Macro1
End If

End Sub
```

And your macro should like something like this:

```
Sub email()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim FName As String


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
FName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    With OutMail
        .To = mailAddress
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = mailSubject
        .Body = "You have missed a valuation date for this project!"

        .Send
    End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can you try and post answer here? I dont have excel right now, I could not try it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dubison - I get run time error 2147 'We need to know who to send this to. Make sure you enter at least one name"

Comment: Hello, I have updated the code. I forgot to define variable. Add `Public mailAddress As String` outside the sub routine or `Dim mailAddress As String` inside the subroutine of worksheet

Comment: I have added the variable but the email still comes up with a blank email address as well as a type mismatch error on the 'If Target.Value = "Overdue" Then line

Comment: is it possible to add some screen shots of your sheets? or at least can you identify which which sheet which column contains which information?

Comment: Thanks Dub, tried it and still getting the same error code. I have tried uploading an image but not enough rep yet to do so

Comment: now I tried it on my computer, all the variables works fine. Please re-check if you input correct macros to correct locations. first set should be in workbook and second set sould ne in a module.

Comment: One more try, can you please put all macro's in the worksheet?

Comment: Tried it now getting run time error 2147 automation error

Comment: I am sorry, I can not help you about that, maybe someone here with better knowledge can help. My last proposal would be to delete the line `FName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name` which I do not see any use of it.

Comment: no problem mate. sorry I could not help further. :)